# Keyboard shortcut to Show Title in Databricks commands

Tags: azure

Is there a keyboard shortcut to 'Show Title' when creating a new command cell in Databricks commands? Or even better, is there a setting to default new commands with titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add title to the cell, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>T</kbd>.